# Percentile ranking in a dataframe. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I have a large dataframe with several thousand rows,and several hundreds columns. Each row is a date, and in each column I have data for that date.
I'll make a smaller example:

```
 DATE    A      B     C
 2012    73,5   27,2  19
 2013    19,5   22,2  33
 2014    33     40    19,56
```

I want to get percentile ranking for all columns for a given date. 
So every column will have percentile value instead of its number, where 95 percentile means that the value was in the top 5%. 
For example A in 2012 would have the highest percentile rating, but it would only be somewhere in the middle in 2014
I presume there has to be a simple function like `pandas.percentile`, or `pandas.rank`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could divide by the max for each year:

```
In [11]: df1 = df.set_index("DATE")

In [12]: df1
Out[12]:
         A     B      C
DATE
2012  73.5  27.2  19.00
2013  19.5  22.2  33.00
2014  33.0  40.0  19.56

In [13]: df1.max(1)
Out[13]:
DATE
2012    73.5
2013    33.0
2014    40.0
dtype: float64

In [14]: df1.div(df1.max(1), axis=0)
Out[14]:
             A         B         C
DATE
2012  1.000000  0.370068  0.258503
2013  0.590909  0.672727  1.000000
2014  0.825000  1.000000  0.489000
```

Comment: For some reason I get a ValueError, due to different shape of operands. I have 673 rows, and 75 columns

Comment: I think I'll just need to set up a loop that will take each row from the dataframe, and divide every entry by the max of this row

Comment: The axis arguments of max and div are critical. Also this will only work for number-like columns. I think max will drop the others hence the ValueError. You can [select_dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) before doing the max/div.